# Why does net.ListenIP this function return error in windows

Tags: go

```golang
func TestListenIP(t *testing.T) {
    _, err := net.ListenIP("ip4:tcp", &net.IPAddr{IP: net.ParseIP("0.0.0.0").To4()})
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

go test .

```
    net_test.go:46: listen ip4:tcp 0.0.0.0: bind: An invalid argument was supplied.
```

But it will run well in Linux(Ubuntu). What's wrong ?

Comment: Have you ruled out possble permissions issues? Creating an IP listener should be a privileged operation on contemporary commodity OSes.

Comment: Yes, I run `go test .` in windows terminal with administrator mode. If don't do this, there will be permission errors.